# Moving python package without messing internal imports

Tags: python, import, package

I wrote a python package that includes many modules. The modules import each other within the package.
Now after it is complete I wish to move my package inside a different package as a subdirectory. But I can't do it because now all the imports get errors because they can't find the modules on their new path.

For example -

In module `my_package.a` I have:

```
x = 5
```

In module `my_package.b`:

```
from my_package.a import x 
print x
```

Before I did: `from my_package import b`, and now I wish to do `from tools.my_package import b`, and get the same result.

What is the right way to change a package logic path without having to add the new path to `sys.path`?

Comment: Can you post your folder structure and an example of how you are currently writing your imports?

Comment: Yes just added a simplified example

Comment: I mean inside of your package. Like in `my_package`, how do you import things internally?

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MatanDavid From what I know, to do things like you're trying to accomplish, you will always have a lot of problems or at least need to change the import statements...but I could be wrong since I'm not an expert. I'm going to upvote your question because I'm curious if someone comes up with a nice solution. In general the import system of Python sucks.

Comment: @MatanDavid Also I've not found yet a good refactoring tool, like there is in Eclipse for Java. If you use PyCharm, it has some nice features, but then a few things are different than working with the IDLE (or other IDEs in general), for example how to import modules. This is very annoying. No standardisation between IDEs and directly from the console of how to important things...

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: Why do you say the import system sucks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use relative imports internally:

```
from .a import x
```

If your module is self-contained, you can relocate it without issues if it uses relative imports.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed for myself, thanks!
Just one problem is with packages I downloaded and were not wrriten that way, Is there a way to do what I originally asked?

Comment: Why are you putting packages you downloaded into your project like this?

Comment: I'm working in a offline network and building a framework for all my workers to use.

Comment: @MatanDavid: There's nothing wrong with appending to `sys.path` in that case, that's what it's for.